# A20 OLinuXino-Micro 4GB from Olimex - understanding GPIOs

Tags: embedded, debian, gpio, adc

i am using a A20 OLinuXino Micro 4GB from Olimex with Debian on SD Card.

I want to use the GPIOs and have some short question about the configuration of the GPIOs. The GPIO-1 connector on the board has pins numbered from 1 to 39. In the manual I have entries like that:

Pin # | Signal name  | Processor pin

23 | PG9 | C19

...

39 | LRADC1 | AB22

In the fex file, I find this:

```
[gpio_para]
gpio_used = 1
gpio_num = 64
...
gpio_pin_10 = port:PG09<0><default><default><default>
```

How is defined that the processor pin C19 is routed to port PG9? 
And port means exactly what?

How is defined that the port PG9 is routed to pin23 of the connector?

Can the gpio_pin_10 designation be chosen arbitrarily?

At the end I would like to use the LRADC1, to sample a signal, but the fex file doesn't have any LRADC1 entry. Why is that?

Maybe somebody could answer may questions in 2 or 3 sentences so it makes sense to the rest of what I read. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [A20-OLinuXino-MICRO schematics](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OLIMEX/OLINUXINO/master/HARDWARE/A20-OLinuXino-MICRO/A20-OLINUXINO-MICRO_Rev_G1.pdf). You can find wiring:

```
PG09 - C19
PG10 - D18
PG11 - C18
(...)
```

In mentioned schematics is also section `GPIO EXTENSION` in which you can find which A20 SoC pin is assigned to which GPIO:

```
PG09 - 23 GPIO-1
PG10 - 25 GPIO-1
```

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_input/output#Ports):

> A GPIO port is a group of GPIO pins (typically 8 GPIO pins) arranged in a group and controlled as a group.

Mapping between physical pin and pin exposed through fex file to operating system is arbitrary. Of course to get correct results you have to assign GPIO ping not. I don't think that fex compiler check anything other then syntax.

In case LRADC0 (again schematics) it us used for buttons (vol +/-, menu, search, ...) and LRADC1 is exposed through GPIO-1 pin 39.